# PDF xref not found

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Using an [online PDF validator](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx),
the basic PDF I'm generating cannot find the `xref` and says something about missing an `endobj`. Checking the `startxref` value, it seems that the `xref` is 473 bytes from the beginning as stated and all of the `obj` have a corresponding `endobj`.

What is invalid about this PDF?

```
%PDF-1.4
%‚„œ”
1 0 obj
<<>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type /Pages/Count 1/MediaBox [0,0,612,792]/Kids [ 4 0 R ]/Resources <</Font []/XObject 1 0 R/ProcSet [ /PDF , /Text , /ImageC ]>>>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Length 6>>
stream
Walrus
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type /Page/Parent 2 0 R/Contents 3 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Title ()/Author ()/Creator (Elixir)/Subject ()/Producer (Gutenex)/Keywords ()/CreationDate (D:20141025152323)>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000035 00000 n 
0000000185 00000 n 
0000000238 00000 n 
0000000297 00000 n 
0000000343 00000 n 

trailer
<<
/Size 7 0 R
/Root 5 0 R
/Info 6 0 R
>>
startxref
473
%%EOF
```

Comment: Please provide a binary copy of the PDF (download, base64, whatever). Embedded textually one cannot be sure what the file really looks like.

Comment: That been said your arrays are all broken, they contain comma symbols, and your content stream contains an unknown operator.

Answer (score 0):

- Your /Size key in the Trailer dictionary is pointing to object ***' 7 0 R '*** which doesn't exist. I guess you meant /Size 7...
- And your arrays shouldn't be comma separated
- Walrus in object ***' 3 0 obj '*** is no valid content stream of operands and operators

  ```
  %PDF-1.4
  %‚„œ”
  1 0 obj
  <<>>
  endobj
  2 0 obj
  <</Type /Pages/Count 1/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]/Kids [ 4 0 R ]/Resources <</Font []/XObject 1 0 R/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageC ]>>>>
  endobj
  3 0 obj
  <</Length 0>>
  stream
  endstream
  endobj
  4 0 obj
  <</Type /Page/Parent 2 0 R/Contents 3 0 R>>
  endobj
  5 0 obj
  <</Type /Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
  endobj
  6 0 obj
  <</Title ()/Author ()/Creator (Elixir)/Subject ()/Producer (Gutenex)/Keywords ()/CreationDate (D:20141025152323)>>
  endobj
  xref
  0 7
  0000000000 65535 f 
  0000000015 00000 n 
  0000000035 00000 n 
  0000000181 00000 n 
  0000000227 00000 n 
  0000000286 00000 n 
  0000000332 00000 n 

  trailer
  <<
  /Size 7
  /Root 5 0 R
  /Info 6 0 R
  >>
  startxref
  462
  %%EOF
  ```

Comment: Considering *Your /Size key in the Trailer dictionary is pointing to object ' 7 0 R ' which doesn't exist* the specification even states: **Size** integer *(Required; shall not be an indirect reference)*, so no matter if that object exists or not, that value is defect.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But one is tempted to do so because we always see those indirect size-references with content streams...